# Password bound credentials

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a Jenkins credential bound to two environment variables that get the user and password from that credential for further use.

Later on the Jenkins job, i launch a Windows command in which i use these variables to create a token using kinit.

I have an issue regarding the password, because it has the following syntax:

```
                              ww&&0864Kbs
```

It seems that using kinit from within a Jenkins job doesn't understands the password and splits it into two different strings and therefore it fails to create the ticket because it fails to authenticate.

Is there any way to escape the password double & ?. I pretend to see all possibilities before changing the password to a more suitable formula.

I have already tried the following :

- ww&&0864Kbs = ww"&""&"0864Kbs --> Unsuccessful
- ww&&0864Kbs = ww^&^&0864Kbs --> Unsuccessful
- ww&&0864Kbs = ww&&0864Kbs --> Unsuccesful
- ww&&0864Kbs = 'ww\&\&0864Kbs' --> Unsuccessful

The syntax i use is : kinit %KB_USER% %KB_PW%

If successful it should return :

New ticket is stored in cache file C:\Users\someuser\krb5cc_someuser

The usual error i get is :

Exception: krb_error 24 Pre-authentication information was invalid (24) Pre-authentication information was invalid
KrbException: Pre-authentication information was invalid (24)

Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication are usually fomat username and password which are separated by a colon in base64 string. For example, 'root' and '123456' are composed into 'root:123456', then in base64 it is 'cm9vdDoxMjM0NTY='. May it be help.